# hyperref: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvipdfm',(hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode. \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}

Tags: hyperref

I'm having a problem to compile the model of the final graduation project that is available to download at this website:
http://www.mec.puc-rio.br/downloads/Template_Latex_Relatorio_Projeto_Graducao_DEM_v3.rar

I don't have a lot of practice with latex, but i've made some projects on it, but not at this level. I've installed MiKTeX and TeXStudio. Here is the error log:

- `hyperref: Wrong DVI mode driver option`dvipdfm',(hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode. \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}`
- `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`

And these are the packages that its on the file:

```
\documentclass[projeto,brazil]{ProjetoFinalDEM}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                      % Fontes com acentos no PDF
\usepackage{multirow}                       % Pacote de linhas multiplas
\usepackage{multicol}                 % Pacote de colunas multiplas
\usepackage[square]{natbib}           % Bibliografia referenciada por [ref]
\usepackage{amsmath}                  % Equação em múltiplas linhas
\usepackage{booktabs}                 % Espessura das linhas em tabelas
\usepackage{amsthm}                   % Numeração de teoremas, proposições, corolarios, exemplos ....
\usepackage{color}                            % Pacote de fontes e caixas coloridas   
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{dsfont}             
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,fixpdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
```

I already have read some related issues and the tips of deleting `dvips` or some related stuff but haven't succeeded.

Any clue how to compile the code to generate do pdf file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure people are willing to download a `.rar` archive.

Answer (score 2):

The class file `ProjetoFinalDEM.cls` contains:

```
\RequirePackage[backref=false,dvipdfm,colorlinks=false,bookmarksopen=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

Since you are using a different driver (pdfTeX or LuaTeX), remove option `dvipdfm`. Both pdfTeX and LuaTeX are auto-detected by `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it worked deleting all dvipdfm from 'ProjetoFinalDEM.cls' . But now im trying to solve the second error from 'natbib', i've searched for possible solutions and any worked for me, i tryied look for missing ',' at the end of line, for empty entries for 'year' and swapping \cite for \citet or \citep and none of these have worked.
Anny suggestion? Thank again for all help

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i solved the second problem:

`Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`

I solved by switching:

```
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
```

for

```
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort]{natbib}
```

Thanks again for all your help. Administrator can close the topic now.